# Storage isn't loading

Tags: storage

I'm trying to clear up space to install Snapchat, and I have no apps to uninstall. So I go into settings to clear space from some apps. I load the "Apps" setting in the storage settings. The screen loaded, but all the apps say "Calculating" under them. And I can't clear the storage in the apps. If anyone knows how to fix this, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: Try from safe mode. Google how to enter safe mode for your device

Comment: clearing app cache is per-app setting, therefore locate the storage settings in the app settings (opposite)